# How to convert Indian Numbers into International System of numbers

Tags: c++, c

I made a program to convert numbers from integer to english in Indian Number format, I am unsure how would I convert this to international system?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void convert(long,char[]);

char *one[]={" "," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven","eight"," Nine"," ten"," eleven"," twelve"," thirteen"," fourteen","fifteen"," sixteen"," seventeen"," eighteen"," nineteen"};
char *ten[]={" "," "," twenty"," thirty"," forty"," fifty"," sixty","seventy"," eighty"," ninety"};


void main()
{
     long n;
     clrscr();
     printf("Enter any 9 digit no: ");
     scanf("%9ld",&n);
     if(n<=0)
                printf("Enter numbers greater than 0");
     else
     {

                  convert((n/10000000),"crore");
                  convert(((n/100000)%100),"lakh");
                  convert(((n/1000)%100),"thousand");
                  convert(((n/100)%10),"hundred");
                  convert((n%100)," ");
     }
     getch();
}

void convert(long n,char ch[])
{
     (n>19)?printf("%s %s ",ten[n/10],one[n%10]):printf("%s ",one[n]);
     if(n)printf("%s ",ch);
}
```

Comment: There are even non-decimal counting systems, so I don't think there is any general approach that goes beyond a function signature of `void ToLanguageString(long num, char* buffer, size_t buflen)`

Comment: The way I do it is to divide the original number up into sets of three digits, and handle the spelling of the values between 1 and 999 with the unit (quintillion, quadrillion, trillion, billion, million, thousand).  So, "123456789101112 = one hundred and twenty-three trillion, four hundred and fifty-six billion, seven hundred and eighty-nine million, one hundred and one thousand, one hundred and twelve".

Comment: Your code seems to leave a lot of unsightly double-spacing in the output, and doesn't include punctuation that I'd regard as necessary.  It also doesn't handle zero, which isn't very elegant (it is a quite important number, but it does require special attention).  For example: `987654321` maps to
`ninety eight crore seventy  six lakh  fifty  four thousand  three hundred  twenty  one`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, how can i make it elegant with proper punctuation?

Comment: and can you give me example of dividing number?

Comment: Well, the example output I showed is from my program; I didn't just type it up.  You have to work harder.  My first step would be to eliminate the spaces from the names in the arrays; that would eliminate the double-spacing (except for trailing blanks).  You then have to note that fifty doesn't get a dash after it, but fifty-one does.  Americans don't like the 'and' in the numbers; the English generally prefer them (I don't know which is preferred in India).  You can put a comma after the spelling of each non-empty (non-zero) group of 3 digits that's followed by some non-zero groups.  Etc.

Comment: As for dividing, I thought that was self-explanatory.  I have `
`static const char *multiple[] = { " quintillion", " quadrillion", " trillion", " billion", " million", " thousand", "" }; static const uint64_t divisor[] = { 1000000000000000000, 1000000000000000, 1000000000000, 1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 1 };` for the control data, …

Comment: …and `char *uint64_to_words(uint64_t u) { int n; const char *pad; char *s; char buffer2[sizeof("seven hundred and seventy-seven")]; s = buffer1; if (u == 0) s = vstrcpy(s, 1, digit[u]); else { pad = ""; for (size_t i = 0; i < DIM(multiple); i++) { n = (int)((u / divisor[i]) % 1000); if (n > 0) { if (i == DIM(multiple) - 1 && n < 100 && u > 1000) pad = " and "; s = vstrcpy(s, 3, pad, spell(n, buffer2), multiple[i]); pad = ", "; } } } return (buffer1); }` for the processing loop in groups of 3 digits.  The `spell()` function deals with numbers between 1 and 999; `vstrcpy()` concatenates strings.

Comment: `buffer1` is 270 characters long; the longest number is `17873873873873873873 = seventeen quintillion, eight hundred and seventy-three quadrillion, eight hundred and seventy-three trillion, eight hundred and seventy-three billion, eight hundred and seventy-three million, eight hundred and seventy-three thousand, eight hundred and seventy-three (length 265)`.  Seventy is the longest word; three, seven and eight are all the same length.